# iOS Cannot update FBSDKCoreKit to latest version

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fbsdk

I try to update FBSDKCoreKit to the latest version (11.2.0) but it does not work because of specified version in Podfile. The current version is 5.15.1.
Xcode version _ 12.4
How can I update to 11.2.0 version?

Thanks

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Name' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Name
pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 10.0'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 2.10.1'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit' 
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' 
pod 'FacebookLogin' 

pod 'DatePickerDialog', '~> 2.0'
pod 'PickerView', '~> 0.3.4'
pod 'PlainPing', '~> 0.5'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.7.0'
pod 'SearchTextField', '~> 1.2.1'

pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.4.2'
pod 'SDWebImage/WebP’

target 'NameTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'NameUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.name == 'Kingfisher' || target.name == 'SearchTextField'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
    end
  end
end
end
```

When I do "pod update --repo-update" or "pod update" it returns this output.

```
CocoaPods 1.11.2 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.2

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 17 dependencies from the Podfile and 28 total pods installed.
```

Podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - DatePickerDialog (2.0)
  - FacebookCore (0.9.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - FacebookLogin (0.9.0):
    - FacebookCore (~> 0.9.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (5.15.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 5.15.1)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.15.1)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (5.15.1)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (5.15.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
  - FBSDKLoginKit (5.15.1):
    - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 5.15.1)
  - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (5.15.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - Firebase/Analytics (8.7.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Core (8.7.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 8.7.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 8.7.0)
  - Firebase/Crashlytics (8.7.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 8.7.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (8.7.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 8.7.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 8.7.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.4)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.4)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 8.7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.4)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.4)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseCore (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.4)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.7.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.4)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - FirebaseInstallations (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.4)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - FirebaseMessaging (8.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.4)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (8.7.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 8.7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.4)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.4)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (8.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.4)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.4)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.1.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.2)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleMaps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.5.2):
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.5.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - KeychainSwift (10.0.0)
  - Kingfisher (4.10.1)
  - libwebp (1.2.0):
    - libwebp/demux (= 1.2.0)
    - libwebp/mux (= 1.2.0)
    - libwebp/webp (= 1.2.0)
  - libwebp/demux (1.2.0):
    - libwebp/webp
  - libwebp/mux (1.2.0):
    - libwebp/demux
  - libwebp/webp (1.2.0)
  - nanopb (2.30908.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30908.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30908.0)
  - PickerView (0.3.4)
  - PlainPing (0.5.2)
  - PromisesObjC (2.0.0)
  - ReachabilitySwift (3)
  - Realm (2.10.2):
    - Realm/Headers (= 2.10.2)
  - Realm/Headers (2.10.2)
  - RealmSwift (2.10.2):
    - Realm (= 2.10.2)
  - SDWebImage (4.4.8):
    - SDWebImage/Core (= 4.4.8)
  - SDWebImage/Core (4.4.8)
  - SDWebImage/WebP (4.4.8):
    - libwebp (< 2.0, >= 0.5)
    - SDWebImage/Core
  - SearchTextField (1.2.4)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - DatePickerDialog (~> 2.0)
  - FacebookLogin
  - FBSDKCoreKit
  - FBSDKLoginKit
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - Firebase/Crashlytics
  - Firebase/Messaging
  - GoogleMaps (~> 2.7.0)
  - KeychainSwift (~> 10.0)
  - Kingfisher (~> 4.0)
  - PickerView (~> 0.3.4)
  - PlainPing (~> 0.5)
  - ReachabilitySwift (~> 3)
  - RealmSwift (~> 2.10.1)
  - SDWebImage (~> 4.4.2)
  - SDWebImage/WebP
  - SearchTextField (~> 1.2.1)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - DatePickerDialog
    - FacebookCore
    - FacebookLogin
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCrashlytics
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleMaps
    - GoogleUtilities
    - KeychainSwift
    - Kingfisher
    - libwebp
    - nanopb
    - PickerView
    - PlainPing
    - PromisesObjC
    - ReachabilitySwift
    - Realm
    - RealmSwift
    - SDWebImage
    - SearchTextField

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  DatePickerDialog: 5e1c24d9fe6506cd45dbc573eed7b0a251b1c09d
  FacebookCore: ba86524b66cfa86d0f8e65d08faa8504a9f732dd
  FacebookLogin: 6cee9fd6e1fe976fe8f7eec199e27b28b14f5d63
  FBSDKCoreKit: 1d5acf7c9d7a2f92bb1a242dc60cae5b7adb91df
  FBSDKLoginKit: f1ea8026a58b52d30c9f2e6a58ca7d813619fb83
  Firebase: bc9325d5ee2041524bac78a5213d0e530c651309
  FirebaseAnalytics: 52768800c2add1d84b751420cb4caaf8195f2c41
  FirebaseCore: f4804c1d3f4bbbefc88904d15653038f2c99ddf7
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: b63732f581a1c6a453ec7241f9ab60b3a5bd3450
  FirebaseCrashlytics: 6fac03d1eef054833b71c929c93ab95c12989728
  FirebaseInstallations: ede6fb72bb6337914e5888b399271259d0c4910c
  FirebaseMessaging: 93227dd71d7888e200baef65043f81acb2b6596e
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 2be61ce546ad074dbe4dd545f222ac6033bb1d9e
  GoogleDataTransport: 85fd18ff3019bb85d3f2c551d04c481dedf71fc9
  GoogleMaps: f79af95cb24d869457b1f961c93d3ce8b2f3b848
  GoogleUtilities: 8de2a97a17e15b6b98e38e8770e2d129a57c0040
  KeychainSwift: f9f7910449a0c0fd2cabc889121530dd2c477c33
  Kingfisher: c148cd7b47ebde9989f6bc7c27dcaa79d81279a0
  libwebp: e90b9c01d99205d03b6bb8f2c8c415e5a4ef66f0
  nanopb: a0ba3315591a9ae0a16a309ee504766e90db0c96
  PickerView: 7edcbbd008682d574eb42916d74a18ebd8dba109
  PlainPing: 41fb93099deb2f5ddbc534a934eb3bf07522d437
  PromisesObjC: 68159ce6952d93e17b2dfe273b8c40907db5ba58
  ReachabilitySwift: f5b9bb30a0777fac8f09ce8b067e32faeb29bb64
  Realm: 0ef72b837fb67e9f4b098bac771ddd72c7fdbb69
  RealmSwift: 07a9ae0505091eda6b2ee7c190c3786d6e90a7b0
  SDWebImage: 783af2c3fa36291a250030c4752ee370a9a51d13
  SearchTextField: 40dc3cc57def5a211f263cac263622c163bbc25a

PODFILE CHECKSUM: a8fdbf33428136b7ed90588af807a6827e1ff40e

COCOAPODS: 1.10.1
```

Comment: What's the podfile look like? Because there might be another pod that accept only the a specific version of FBSDKCoreKit and not the last one.  Did you do a `pod update`?

Comment: You need to show the Podfile.lock, I mistype/forgot the "lock".

Comment: I have attached Podfile.lock file

Answer (score 1):

When you run `pod install` it will create a `Podfile.lock` to specify the correct version to use, you can use that lock file to share across your team to make sure everyone install same version of library on their machine. Pod lock file contains like:

```
  - RxCocoa (5.1.3):
    - RxRelay (~> 5)
    - RxSwift (~> 5)
  - RxRelay (5.1.3):
    - RxSwift (~> 5)
  - RxSwift (5.1.3)
```

If you want to update, run `pod update --repo-update` instead then you can recheck the `Podfile.lock` again.

Comment: I do pod update --repo-update but it does not update, I have edited the question

Comment: Show the podfile.lock (I forgot "lock" in my comment on your question >_<, sound too close to "look & like")). As said another pod might limit it.

Comment: so your cocoapod is outdated, upgrade it by the way you install `sudo gem install cocoapods`. you can think cocoapods is a mac application to manage remote libraries for your ios source code. Podfile is the configuration file to tell your cocoapod fetch correct libraries & versions

Comment: I have attached Podfile.lock file and I have run sudo gem install cocoapods, should I repeat pod update after that?

Comment: of course, upgrade the app, then use the app to upgrade your libs

Comment: I did it but FBSDK version is 5.15.1. 1:( .  1. sudo gem install cocoapods, 2. deleted  Pod.lock and Pod files, 3. pod install

Comment: have you tried `pod install --repo-update`, there's another thing call pod spec you can research to see how it works but just add `--repo-update` to make sure you local machine contains latest pod specs.

Comment: Yes, I also run pod install --repo-update, but Podfile.lock file contains FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.15.1) version

Answer (score 1):

Extract of your podfile.lock:

```
- FacebookLogin (0.9.0):
  - FacebookCore (~> 0.9.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.0)
```

Here, `FacebookLogin` in version `0.9.0` needs a `FBSDKCoreKit` of version `5.x`.

So `FacebookLogin` is the one limiting the `FBSDKCoreKit` version.

So is there a newer version of `FacebookLogin` that allow a upper version of `FBSDKCoreKit`? It doesn't seem so according to the [release page](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/releases).

You could specify the wanted version of `FBSDKCoreKit` with `pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 11.2.0'`, but then, you should have a conflict, because `FacebookLogin` supports only `5.x`.

So, you can't.

Either wait, ask/propose updates on the repo (if they accept MR), etc.

Comment: that's the thing (y)

Comment: is there a way to update the 0.9.0 version?

Comment: By creating your OWN version (ie, a fork), but beware of compatibility based on the current version, and maybe propose it to the current one with a MergeRequest. That's possible, if the code is open, of course...