# Unable to get the last version of Amplify pod library

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I can't raise Amplify library version when using plugin pods.
I need at least version 1.14.0 of it to use AWSS3PluginPrefixResolver to setup custom storage paths.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/releases/tag/v1.14.0

If I install the library without plugins I get the newest pod version - 1.24.1. But if I try to install it with plugins, it gives me the option to get a version no higher than 1.5.0.

My podFile setup

```
    platform :ios, '12.1'
    
    target '---------------' do
    
     use_frameworks!
      pod 'AWSS3'
      pod 'AWSCognito'
      pod 'AWSCore'
      pod 'AWSMobileClient'
      pod 'Amplify'
      pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin'
      pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
      pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin'
      pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSDataStorePlugin'
      
      pod 'StepIndicator', '~> 1.0.8'
      pod 'CodableKeychain', '~> 1.0.0'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Core'
      pod 'CocoaMQTT'
      pod 'SKCountryPicker', '~> 2.0.0'
      pod 'DropDown'
      pod 'CropViewController'
      pod 'Firebase'
      pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
      pod 'BugfenderSDK', '~> 1.10'
      pod 'SDWebImage'
      pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'
      pod 'JGProgressHUD'
      pod 'AYPopupPickerView'
      pod 'SDWebImage'
      pod 'Alamofire'
      pod 'SwiftyJSON'

      pod 'WWCalendarTimeSelector', :git => 'https://github.com/weilsonwonder/WWCalendarTimeSelector.git', :commit => '0fc6bcce08ec997ca387dec29c071b32efbe33f7'
    
      target '---------------Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end
    
      target '---------------UITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end
    
    end
```

Is there any way to get the latest version of the plugins?

============================

**Answer**

The libraries required a different versions of the AWSCognito pod. I removed it and added other pods: 'AWSPinpoint' and 'AWSPluginsCore'. I took them from [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSCognito)
The Aplify version of the library was installed by '~> 1.14.0' and it works!

Comment: Well I have been working on this but with Package Manager. Did you tried Package manager?

Comment: Which command do you use to update the pod? If you're updating just one pod, my first guess would be that there are transient dependencies that are also used by some other pods, so you'll need to update other pods that share the same transient dependencies. For the sake of finding out, I'd try updating all pods at once.

Comment: Do you do `pod update` at least? Could you share the podfile.lock? It's saying there if another lib needs that "low" version...

Comment: @Larme I did it in such ways: 
1. Pod update

2. `rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"` -> `rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"` -> `pod update` or `pod install`

Comment: @Kudos I can't use Package Manager because the git sub-project is used here ( and it causes conflicts

Comment: @VadimBelyaev  I did it in different ways. I cleared the cache of all pods and reinstall them.
Maybe I need to use concrete branch from git to install concrete version?

Comment: What's the output of the `pod update` command?

Comment: Could you share the Podfile.lock? You could spot like I did on another question which dependency is limiting the Amplify version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188839/1801544 if that's the real issue...

Comment: But you could trigger the explaination with by forcing the version of Amplify: `pod 'Amplify', '~> 1.14.0'` instead of `pod 'Amplify'`, and you should see: `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Amplify" AmplifyPlugins/AWSDataStorePlugin was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on AWSPluginsCore (= 1.5.0) was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on Amplify (= 1.5.0) Specs satisfying the `Amplify (~> 1.14.0), Amplify (= 1.5.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`...

Comment: Guys, thank you very much!
I figured out what the problem is. The libraries required a different versions of the AWSCognito pod. I removed it and added other pods: 'AWSPinpoint' and
  'AWSPluginsCore'. I took them from here https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSCognito 
The Aplify version of the library was installed by '~> 1.14.0' and now everything is cool!

I'll add a description of the question. Might help someone too